# Different maxsizes for different type files in Yii

Tags: file-upload, yii

I upload files with yii and i want verify those files.
But for different types of files - different sizes.
for example
  - if user want upload jpg or pdf file - maxSize - 10 MB.
  - for video files - maxSize - 150 MB.

How can i make so ?

This variant doesn't work, because work only second rule.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('files', 'validateFiles', 'types' => 'jpg, gif, png, pdf, doc, docx', 'maxSize' => 10 * 1024 * 1024, 'on' => 'upload'),
        array('files', 'validateFiles', 'types' => 'avi, mpg, flv, mov, mpeg, mp4, 3gp, wmv', 'maxSize' => 150 * 1024 * 1024, 'on' => 'upload'),
}

public function validateFiles($attribute, $params)
{
    $validator = CValidator::createValidator('file', $this, $attribute, $params);
    $files = array();
    foreach(CUploadedFile::getInstances($this, $attribute) as $file) {
        $this->$attribute = $file;
        $files[] = $file;
        $validator->validate($this, $attribute);
    }
    $this->$attribute = $files;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution - create new Validator - for example PictureVideoValidator
and in this file choose which of file type and make validation.

```
<?php
class PictureVideoValidator extends CValidator
{
    public $allowEmpty = false;
    public $maxSizePicture = 4194304; // 4 Mb
    public $maxSizeVideo = 157286400; // 150 Mb

    protected function validateAttribute($object, $attribute)
    {
        $file = $object->$attribute;

        if (!$file instanceof CUploadedFile) {
            $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($object, $attribute);
            if ($file == null)
                return $this->emptyAttribute($object, $attribute);
        }


        $type = CFileHelper::getMimeType($file->tempName);
        list($type, $subtype) = @explode('/', $type);

        $allowedTypes = array('image', 'video');

        if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
            $message = Yii::t('ext', 'File cannot be uploaded because it is not a valid image/video file');
            $this->addError($object, $attribute, $message);
            return;
        }

        $fileSize = filesize($file->tempName);
        if ($type == 'image') {
            $maxSize = $this->maxSizePicture;
        } else if ($type == 'video') {
            $maxSize = $this->maxSizeVideo;
        }

        if ($fileSize > $maxSize) {
            $message = Yii::t('ext', 'The file "{fileName}" is too large. Its size cannot exceed {maxSize} bytes.');
            $this->addError($object, $attribute, $message, array(
                '{fileName}' => $file->getName(),
                '{maxSize}' => $this->maxSizePicture
            ));
        }
    }

    protected function emptyAttribute($object, $attribute)
    {
        if (!$this->allowEmpty) {
            $message = $this->message !== null ? $this->message : Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.');
            $this->addError($object, $attribute, $message);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may allow the max. filesize to upload, then validate upon the file is received - validate in the model or in the controller. Anyway, the file size is validated also in Yii ONLY after the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it will not work.

If the code validate against the first array, it will fail against the second one and visa versa. Your model will never validate unless both conditions are met.

The best way to achieve this would be to expand the validateFiles function and check for the extensions/filesizes there.

For example, First change the rules function as a combination of both

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('files', 'validateFiles', 'types' => 'jpg, gif, png, pdf, doc, docx, avi, mpg, flv, mov, mpeg, mp4, 3gp, wmv', 'maxSize' => 150 * 1024 * 1024, 'on' => 'upload')
    )
}
```

That way, the check for the file types is already done, and the check for the total maximum file size is done.

After that, alter the validateFiles function to check the extensions/filesize